# CrudRepository java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this `controller` class for my index page.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView main() {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "user", new User());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView checkUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return new ModelAndView("main", "user", user);
    }
```

But when I start my project Tomcat give me this error:

```
16:11:23.561 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [com.nikita.controllers.LoginController] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: demo_war_exploded
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@6504e3b2
] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nikita</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I already delete .m2 folder and download all dependencies again

*UserRepository* class:

```
package com.nikita.database;

import com.nikita.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Am I have to implement UserRepository interface or it will implements by itself?

Comment: Have you created the pom.xml using start.spring.io ? All your starter dependencies should not specify the versions, since it is inherited from parent pom.

Comment: @Lorelorelore is correct, no versions on your starter dependencies are required. I quickly sketched a tiny project based on your `pom.xml` and it seems to start without problems. Can you make sure that the `spring-data-commons.jar` in which `CrudRepository` belongs, exists in your war libs? If not try to re-import your maven dependencies, clean and compile/package your project from scratch

Comment: In Addition to @Lorelorelore and @pleft answers, you also have duplicated dependencies: `spring-core` is already present in  `spring-boot-starter-test`, `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc` are already present in `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-jdbc` is present `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I would suggest to delete all them and keep only the starters.